# What does this red icon on my panel mean?

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management

This red icon.... It showed up after I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04LTS; I can't figure out how to ditch it. It seems to be a notification thing.  I am at a loss.  The icon is this one:

[image: red mark]

I clicked it and read this:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:
>
> ```
> 'Error: BrokenCount>0'.
> ```
>
> This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/272937/problem-with-mergelist-var-lib-apt-lists-ppa-launchpad-net-gwibber-daily-ppa-ub The first answer in the link solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's letting you know that the package system is in a broken state (eg. some of the packages are in a broken state). You can try to resolve this by running the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried that and it did nothing :(

Comment: Try updating the system and see if you get any errors "sudo apt-get update".  Paste any errors you get into your original question.

Comment: I deleted the packages in question.  Not only is the icon gone, but my system is running faster.

Comment: What packages were in question?

Comment: Nice .. it work like charm , do not forget to "sudo apt-get update" after running above command :)

Comment: The above command returned that their is nothing to do. But then I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade and that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this same red and white warning icon and identical error code after having tried to install the wrong package accidentally (i386 on amd64 - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) To resolve I...

1. ran `dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/packages` in terminal to get a list of installed packages
2. removed the package that I had just tried to install using the name of the package as appearing in the above list and this command `sudo apt-get purge name-of-package-here`
3. ran the command above `sudo apt-get -f install` thanks tgm4883
4. removed some redundant packages with `sudo apt-get autoremove` (the suggestion appeared in terminal after running the prior command.) Either here or the command before resulted in the warning/error disappearing
5. I then ran `sudo apt-get update` which took much longer than usual and everything seems to be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Please get correct package name which is been broken. You can use following command to get all package list.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > list.txt
```

Find correct package name from the list(created in home folder).

And use following command to remove package forcefully.

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P PACKAGE NAME
```

ex- `sudo dpkg --force-all -P texlive-pstrick-doc` (texlive-pstrick-doc is package name)

Next run update command.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This works for me.
Thanks

Comment: @EricCarvalho how do i know which package has affected the system from the list of packages ?

Comment: @devGeek This answer is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new profile/login. Maybe it's related to profile only. I tried everything mentioned in all help on diff websites. At the end, I created a new profile and log in. It's resolved the issue. There is no red circle Icon in the top bar in this profile.