# Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gwibber-daily_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en

Tags: package-management, ppa

I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It was all well. But suddenly from yesterday whenever I try to install something it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gwibber-daily_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

And when I try to run Synaptic Package Manager it shows:

> ```
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
> ```
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> ```
> 'E:Encountered a section with no Package: header,
>  E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gwibber-daily_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en, 
>  E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
> ```

What should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, I haven't installed any ppa for gwibber recently and ever. Anyway, I just have removed the line: 'ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber' in System Settings-> Software Sources -> Other software. But it didn't solve my problem. Other ideas needed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed a PPA for gwibber recently?

If so, I would guess it is a problem with the repository.
Check in

**System Settings > Software Sources > Other sources**

and look for a line `ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber`

Remove it or disable it and it should solve your issue (but you won't have the latest version of gwibber anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by a malformed file in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. The reason could be most probably an error on the previously mentioned PPA, power loss while updating the software sources or a problem with your hard disk.

In any case it *should* be safe to simply delete the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory. Then fetch the files that belong there from the web again by running `sudo apt-get update`.

Make a backup first (just in case I'm wrong and deleting the folder isn't safe):

```
tar -cfz ~/lists_backup.tar.gz /var/lib/apt/lists
```

Then delete the folder and update it:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have tampered with your sources and added a PPA as the error shows.

I find it easiest to fix such errors with [Yppa manager](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/y-ppa-manager-0084-is-released.html) from noobslab.