# Error opening the cache: could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (13: permission denied)

Tags: aptitude

I got the following error:

```
Error opening the cache: could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (13: permission denied)
```

I cannot update my system at all. When I hit update I get that all the PPA's where not found

I've tried all the answers that I found including:

1. Creating a clone of this file and renaming in case it was corrupted.
2. Getting back a backup (.old)
3. Fixing permissions (actually I went on and gave 777)

None of the above resolved my problem. Is there a painless way to reinstall Aptitude?

EDIT: Output of `stat`

```
  File: ‘/var/lib/dpkg/status’
  Size: 2720129     Blocks: 5320       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 5389567     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-10-19 08:32:02.481638343 +0300
Modify: 2015-10-16 23:22:37.787905868 +0300
Change: 2015-10-16 23:22:37.795905748 +0300
 Birth: -
```

`sudo apt-get update`

This produces a lot of output which I am not allowed to post here. But the errors go like this:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources                                                                                                                                          
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                   
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                   
Fetched 174 kB in 8s (21,6 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                          
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And sudo aptitude update follows the same pattern:

```
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                                                                                                                                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources                                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                    
Fetched 112 kB in 8s (14,0 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                           
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/utopic-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache
```

Besides that, permanand red icon on the top next to my network monitor there is a red icon

[What does this red icon on my panel mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197595/what-does-this-red-icon-on-my-panel-mean)

Edit: `sudo lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

Comment: The command was not found. I do not thing I have this package installed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake `stat /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: You ran your commands as root (using sudo)?

Comment: yes I did. `sudo stat /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: And you have started with `sudo aptitude ...`?

Comment: No. I just copied and pasted the command you posted on your comment and prefixed sudo.

Comment: We mean whether you ran `aptitude update`/`aptitude upgrade`/whatever command reported the error with `sudo`. Besides that, can you try `apt-get` instead of `aptitude`? Syntax is usually the same. Does that fail too?

Comment: For updating I use apt. I.e `apt-get update`

Comment: without `sudo`?

Comment: Always with sudo

Comment: So what is the **exact** command that produces the error and what commands work (concerning `apt-get *` and `aptitude *`)?

Comment: Updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: What command produce the `Error opening the cache: could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (13: permission denied)` error message?

Comment: None, this is written when I click the red icon on top which is the same as this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/197595/what-does-this-red-icon-on-my-panel-mean

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Edited the question and added the output

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg -D` and `apt-get check`